# Given $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}$ how can I find its derivative?

Tags: derivatives

Given that $f(x)$ = $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}$ towards infinity, how can I find the derivative?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**:$$ f\left( x \right) =\sqrt { x+\sqrt { x+\sqrt { x+... }  }  } \\ f\left( x \right) =\sqrt { x+f\left( x \right)  } \\ f^{ 2 }\left( x \right) -f\left( x \right) -x=0\\ f\left( x \right) =\frac { 1+\sqrt { 1+4x }  }{ 2 } $$

Comment: actually, we know that $f(x) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$ since $f$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @Giuseppe,good point,thank you